# TFS version control of work items (e.g. Requirements etc.) How can I tell what a specific requirement said "one year ago"?

Tags: tfs

I can roll the code back to a previous version (of code), but how do I see what a particular requirement said at that point in time?

Comment: Requirement? As in a requirement within a spec?

Comment: Do you mean Task? What was in the task comment at the specific time?

Comment: I could mean task, however specifically I'm interested in what a Requirement work-item said when I commited a change (in the past) and not what it says right now.

Comment: Using the API it should be possible to achieve. this I believe I saw a tool to do this exact thing once, unfortunately I can't find it again.

Comment: Actually I wonder if you can use the ASOF command http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130326(v=vs.80).aspx + http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Time-travelling-with-Work-Item-Queries-In-TFS-2010.aspx

Comment: @Betty: was the tool you mention the one I linked into my answer?

Comment: Probably was, I do read Tarun's blog.

Comment: hmm, it sounds as though it can't be done without rolling my own. @Betty slap your ASOF response in an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. Cheers people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use WIQL using the ASOF command.

Here are some resources that may help:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130326(v=vs.80).aspx
- http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Time-travelling-with-Work-Item-Queries-In-TFS-2010.aspx
- http://wiqlinq.codeplex.com/
- http://blogs.developpeur.org/miiitch/archive/2008/03/31/linq-to-wiql.aspx
- http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2011/11/21/export-tfs-work-items-to-an-xml-file-using-tfs-power-tools.aspx

There is also a tool called Fissum (http://fissum.codeplex.com/) which has an interesting group by feature, might not work on custom fields or might be a pain to run individually on all work items.

Answer (score 1):

Open the work item and look in the history tab.  Then click through to see what all changes have been made to the work item.

Just expand any "Show Changes (Fields)" items you find.